# How to make Discord Bot do multiple different responses?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This is what my discord bot.js looks like.

Basically, I thought that when I type in "ten bot je fakt sračka" it gives one of the responses in the array.

If I type in "ahoj", it gives that response with a few hearts.

And also when I type in "test", it should reply with "test".

Now, when I run the bot and type in any of the three messages, if only replies "test" to "test". Nothing else gets a response. What do I do?

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.login("TOKEN");

client.on("ready", readyDiscord);

function readyDiscord() {
    console.log("123");
}

const replies = ["Stop it!", "Bot lives matter! <:ragey:776017536973013003>", "no", "<:jakjestvbiblipsno:776002959665266709>"];

client.on("message", gotMessage);

function gotMessage(msg) {
    console.log(msg.content);
    if (msg.content === "ten bot je fakt sračka") {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * replies.length);
        msg.channel.send(replies[index]);
    }
}

function gotMessage(msg) {
    console.log(msg.content);
    if (msg.content === "ahoj") {
        msg.reply("Ahoj <3<3<3");
    }
}

function gotMessage(msg) {
    console.log(msg.content);
    if (msg.content === "test") {
        msg.reply("test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you keep overriding your function 'gotMessage' and the last declaration of it is where you reply with test.

```
client.on('message', gotMessage);

function gotMessage(msg) {
    console.log(msg.content);
    if (msg.content === 'ten bot je fakt sračka') {
      const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * replies.length);
      msg.channel.send(replies[index]); 
    } else if (msg.content === 'ahoj') {
      msg.reply('Ahoj <3<3<3');
    } else if (msg.content === 'test') {
      msg.reply('test');
    }
}
```

Here you have all the if statements in one declaration of `gotMessage`. Since it isn't overridden, each if will be accounted for. It is also better to use `else if` in this situation since you're checking if a value is equal to one thing or another.

P.S. Never share your bot's login token online, otherwise other people can mess with it

Comment: Ah true, I didn't copy it at first, but decided to include the entire code with text too. I will reset it then. Thanks for the code! I am really new to Python and I just thought that I could solve it all by copypasting the prompts.